# PowerShell script to copy two files from a static location to a location with two variables in the in path

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a PowerShell script to copy a couple of files from a static location to a location with two variables in the path

Example

I need to copy the two files to the following location for each profile that exists on many machines (laptop / PC).  The ultimate plan is to role this script out to every machine that needs it via group policy

`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Communicator\$sip_user@domain.net$`

`%username%` and `$sip_user@domain.net$` is unique to each user

Thanks in advance for any help (I'm struggling with this)

Sandy

Answer (score 0):

First of all create CSV with structure like below (users.csv):

```
Name,Sip
login1,login1@gmail.com
```

The run following statement:

```
Import-Csv C:\PATH_TO_CSV\users.csv | foreach{cp C:\YOUR_PATH\YOUR_FILE ("C:\Users\"+$_.Name+"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Communicator\"+$_.Sip)}\
```

Update
Script for run for current user:

```
$userName = [Environment]::UserName;
$domain = [Environment]::UserDomainName;

# Look for a user
$Rech = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$rc = $Rech.filter = "((sAMAccountName=$userName))"
$rc = $Rech.SearchScope = "subtree"
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress");
$theUser = $Rech.FindOne()

Write-host "Username is" $userName
Write-host "Domain is" $domain
if ($theUser -ne $null)
{
  Write-Host "Mail is" $theUser.Properties["mail"]
  Write-Host "SIP is" $theUser.Properties["msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Garath. I've updated my question a little the script will need to work for many machines and I plan to roll the script out using group policy

Comment: So the script will be run for current user? And one more question how you can get SIP for current login?

Comment: Did you look at: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/150945/Get-SIP-address-from-active-directory for getting SIP?

Comment: Hello Garath thanks for the link on obtaining the SIP.  Yes the script would be ideal if it ran for the current user

Comment: I added updated script. BTW on stackoverflow you do not have to thanks , instead mark response as useful (+1) or as answer